# Storing a password for user impersonation

Tags: c#

I am currently working on a simple WinForms/C# application which archives data in a structured and consistent manner. The intended users don't have write access to the archive folder, and are only supposed to be able to write using the application.

Since users should not get additional rights, I need to supply the application with the credentials of some generic service user in order to start user impersonation. Because the users are not supposed to know those credentials, they would have to be stored somehow (I'd prefer locally since I have no experience using databases and whatnot).
Is there any way to securely store the credentials without the end user having to know/do anything about them? Or is there another, better way to go about solving this problem?

I know that questions about password storage are frequent, and I have tried my best to find an answer to my specific problem, but all of the threads I could find are looking to store a password known by the user.

Comment: Nothing will be absolutely secure as the users have access to the machine and the application. It's about risk vs reward. Would your users find the password if you simply base64 encoded it and hid it away in application settings? If you encrypted the password would they be able to decompile your application to find the key? Don't waste a lot of time building Fort Knox if a simple wooden fence is enough ;-)

Comment: In my opinion, the security level I was asked to implement for this is way overkill, since the application will only be used by/available to employees, and if they wanted to find the password in question they'd barely have to try

Comment: App.config file sections can be encrypted by the framework and accessed without the need to manually decrypt. You could possibly leverage that to store the password so no prying eyes can *easily* discover it. Though Luaans point holds that doing so still isn't the best idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest solution is to actually create a service, which runs under a user with the correct permissions. Your Winforms application would then just use a tight interface to the service to tell it what needs to be done. How feasible this is depends on what exactly you're trying to do.

Trying to do this using just the winforms application is tricky. If a user application can do something, so can the user. Remember, there's no such thing as "application permissions" - only user permissions. The GUI application will run as *some* user, and that user can do everything the application can.

Comment: I second this approach.

Comment: I will look into creating a service, but I'm unsure if thats anything someone of my skill level can create easily. At the moment, it's the idea to have a user that is allowed to write inside that directory, so using only winforms seemed logical to me.

Comment: @DominikS It's the only way to truly separate the user permissions. But it might be that something simpler would work just as well for you - for example, the user can have write access to the folder, but not the files or directories he doesn't own (e.g. didn't create). You could even have a service that takes ownership of the files in the archive directory when they're done being written. But again, this all depends on what exactly your requirements are - we can only help you with specific questions, not software design :)

Comment: What additional Information would you need? All the application needs to do is paste a selected file into the restricted directory, without the user having write access. In any case thank you for the answers, I hadn't considered using a service until now.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not a matter of having more information, even if you provided every detail of your business environment and software requirements it would still be considered off topic as too broad/opinion based.

Answer (score -1):

you can hash passwords like below

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public static string EncodePasswordToBase64(string password)
{  byte[] bytes   = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password);
   byte[] inArray = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1").ComputeHash(bytes);
   return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
}
```

Comment: And that helps... how? How do you use that hashed password to impersonate a Windows user?

Comment: @rishit_s  This is wrong. A one-way hash is used for verification of a password entered by a user, to avoid storing it. You cannot generate a password from the hash, and a password is what is needed to impersonate an account. You can use encryption (not hashing) for this, but I'd go with Luaan's approach instead, as that is more secure.